# How to calculate amortized cost of the push operations for a resizing stack

Tags: solution-verification, algorithms, fractions

In *Algorithms* (4th ed.) by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne at page 199 it's illustrated how the cost of resizing a stack (based on a dynamic array) is amortized among the most recent push operations:

> **Proposition E.** In the resizing array implementation of Stack
> (Algorithm 1.1), the average number of array accesses for any sequence
> of push and pop operations starting from an empty data structure is
> constant in the worst case.
>
> **Proof sketch:** For each push operation that
> causes the array to grow (say from size N to size 2N), consider the
> n/2 - 1 push operations that most recently caused the stack size to
> grow to k, for k from n/2 + 2 to N. Averaging the 4N array accesses to
> grow the array to size 2N (2N array accesses to copy the N items and
> 2N array accesses to initialize an array) with n/2 - 1 array accesses
> (one for each push), we get an average cost of 9 array accesses for
> each of these n/2 - 1 push operations. Establishing this proposition
> for any sequence of push and pop operations is more intricate (see
> Exercise 1.4.32)

I cannot do the math to get the `9` result stated in the proof sketch:

$\require{cancel}$

$$\frac{4n+n/2-1}{n/2-1} = \frac{8n+n-2}{1\cancel2} \times  \frac{1\cancel2}{n-2} = \frac{9n-2}{n-2} = ???$$

Can anybody show me the right way to get this result? Did I misunderstand the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $n / 2 - 1$ push operations that most recently caused the stack size to grow **together** with the last operation which causes the array to grow. Then you get one more operation both in numerator and denominator, thus the fractions equal to $9$.